# Using hasura with flutter , getting the following errors , Graphql version ^3.0.0

Tags: flutter, dart, graphql, hasura

[image]Using Hasura with flutter, getting the following errors, Graphql version ^3.0.0

```
{
    "resource": "/D:/example_hasura1/lib/county.dart",
    "owner": "dart",
    "code": "argument_type_not_assignable",
    "severity": 8,
    "message": "The argument type 'Widget Function(QueryResult, {refetch: void Function()})' can't be assigned to the parameter type 'Widget Function(QueryResult, {fetchMore: dynamic Function(FetchMoreOpti[![enter image description here][1]][1]ons), refetch: Future<QueryResult> Function()})'.",
    "source": "dart",
    "startLineNumber": 24,
    "startColumn": 9,
    "endLineNumber": 24,
    "endColumn": 347,
    "tags": []
}
```

Comment: Please check the question guidelines and improve your question: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 2, accepted):

instead of:
builder: (QueryResult result, {VoidCallback refetch}) {
  ...
}

add a third parameter like this:
builder: (QueryResult result, {VoidCallback refetch, FetchMore fetchMore}) {
  ...
}

and I can see that you're not checking errors. But if you do, then make sure to change it from .error to .hasException

Hope it works